# window.innerWidth/Height gets corrupted by resizing three.js renderer on orientation change

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile, three.js

I might have discovered a Chrome Bug related to three.js/WebGL.

I have set up a simple project demonstrating the issue [here](https://github.com/PeterKey/sizeBug-threejs). It simply initialises a fullscreen three.js canvas, resizes the renderer on resize events and prints window.innerWidth/Height to the console. **(The code was created by one of the three.js contributors and should be the standard way of implementing auto-resizing. [Related three.js issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12988))**

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <script src="three.js"></script>
  <script>
    var scene, camera, renderer, mesh;
    init();
    animate();
    function init() {
      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
      camera.position.z = 1;

      var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
      var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add( mesh );

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      window.addEventListener( 'resize', resize );

      console.log( 'width: ' + window.innerWidth, 'height: ' + window.innerHeight );
    }

    function resize() {

      console.log( 'width: ' + window.innerWidth, 'height: ' + window.innerHeight );

      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }

    function animate() {

      requestAnimationFrame( animate );

      mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
      mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**How to reproduce the issue**

[**>>> Link to repository**](https://github.com/PeterKey/sizeBug-threejs)

1. Open `test.html` in Chrome
2. Fire up Devtools
3. Toggle Device Toolbar
4. Select a device *(for this example Nexus 6P)*
5. Switch from landscape to portrait mode and observe console output

My console output:

```
width: 412 height: 732      # portrait mode
width: 732 height: 412      # landscape mode
width: 732 height: 1301     # portrait mode
width: 732 height: 412      # landscape mode
```

The first time I switch from landscape to portrait mode the values of window.innerHeight/Width aren't correct anymore. It should be 412x732 instead of 732x1301.

Excluding the line `renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)` solves the problem.

**Related Devices**

I was able to reproduce this bug on 2 different MacBooks (2016, 2013) **[Chrome v. 63.0.3239.108]** and on my Android Phone (Redmi 4X, Android 7.1.2) **[Chrome v.  63.0.3239.111]**

It'd be nice if somebody could confirm this behaviour.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: The link to the repository is right at the top. The second sentence.
I edited my question to make it clearer. [(Link to project)](https://github.com/PeterKey/sizeBug-threejs)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error today. I tried using document.documentElement.client[Width or Height] and it gave me the right dimensions. I didn't implement my solution yet, but something that could be good would be to check if the last time you checked your dimensions it looked like the dimensions from innerWidth like :

```
if(lastDims.height !== nowDims.width) { /*Or something similar, you get the idea*/
    //The dimensions are ok assuming lastDims was ok too
}
// or
const width = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth);
const height = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
```

Also, I'm using fabric.js (canvas) and screenfull.js (fullscreen API), not three.js. I am using Chrome though.

(As I was writing this, I installed Firefox) I just tested my app and it works fine in Firefox, so that might be a problem in Chrome itself when handling the window.inner[stuff] after the fullscreen API has done its thing... I might be wrong but, hey, I got the right dimension in the end!

**Edit**: Soooo thought about it, you might already found your solution since it's 2018 now...
**I swear, last edit**: This is a Chrome(Chromium) bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=833440&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=window.innerWidth&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=